# PySide how to tell if a push button has been clicked?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a layout with 5 buttons which I act as "menus", so you click on one button and one view will show up, you click another button and another view shows up. I need to find out which button is clicked so I can do something based on which button is pressed. Something like

```
if button1_is_clicked:
    do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

What would be the best way to approach this?
Here is my code:
I want to be able to change the stylesheet of the button, so an active state and a non-active state

```
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui
import VulcanGui

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Program(QtGui.QMainWindow, VulcanGui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """ Initialize and setup the User Interface """
        super(Program, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        """ Populate the Main Area """
        self.mainArea.setHtml(self.intro_text())


        """ Button Signal/Slots """
        self.introButton.toggled.connect(self.intro_area)
        self.runVulcanButton.clicked.connect(self.vulcan_run_area)
        self.vulcanLogButton.clicked.connect(self.vulcan_log_area)
        self.hostFileButton.clicked.connect(self.edit_host_area)
        self.configEditButton.clicked.connect(self.edit_config_area)            



    def intro_text(self):
        content_file = open("../content/intro_text.html").read()
        return content_file

    '''
    Get the content to print
    '''
    def intro_area(self):
        content_file = open("../content/intro_text.html").read()
        self.mainArea.setHtml(content_file)


    '''
    Function that will display the data when the 'Run Vulcan' button is pressed
    '''
    def vulcan_run_area(self):
        self.mainArea.setPlainText("Button Two ")


    '''
    Function that will display the data when the 'Vulcan Log' button is pressed
    '''
    def vulcan_log_area(self):
        self.mainArea.setPlainText("Button Three")


    '''
    Function that will display the data when the 'Edit Host File' button is pressed
    '''
    def edit_host_area(self):
        self.mainArea.setPlainText("Button Four")

    '''
    Function that will display the data when the 'Edit Config File' button is pressed
    '''
    def edit_config_area(self):
        self.mainArea.setPlainText("Button Five")



#--------------------------------------------------------------------------



if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys


    program = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mWindow = Program()
    mWindow.show()
    sys.exit(program.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you learn the basics of Qt to get acquainted with signals and slots.

You need to make the initially visible `QPushButton`s checkable (otherwise the 'revealed' buttons will only appear whilst the button is held down), and connect the `toggled(bool)` signal to the `setVisible(bool)` slot of the buttons you want to 'reveal'.  Obviously for the buttons that are initially invisible, you would have to call `setVisible(false)` upon instantiation.

There are other, more reusable, ways of achieving the same effect - but this will get you started.